# Name of file in cache android

Tags: android

I'm trying to save file `0_0.xml` in cache. So I do it like this

```
String fileName = "0_0.xml"
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
    ...
} else {
    file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        fos.write("some_string".getBytes());
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

I've run my application for several times and wondered that it always could not find this file (if not `file.exists()` I write it like I described above) so it created new one each time. After that I listed all files in my cache and got something like this:

[image: cached files]

The question is why does my file change it's name and how can I access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call [`File.createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) to create the file.  `createTempFile()` will compute a new, unique, name for your temporary file to avoid collisions with other operations that also need a temporary file.

If you want to keep the file and find it again, don't use `createTempFile()` to generate new and unique names.  Instead use the same object (`file`) that you used when you checked to see if it existed.